# Float property doesn't work when paragraph is longer than one line

Tags: html, css, css-float

I was trying to align some `<p>` element on the left, using the `float: left;` css property.

When the text is on one single line, it is correctly aligned on the left, like on picture below :
[image]

But when the text is at least two lines, the text is not left aligned anymore, and gets centered, because of the `text-align: center;` property that it inherits from the `body` :
[image]

I know I could remove the `text-align` property from the `body` but what I would like, is to know why it happens.

Anyone knows why ? Thanks in advance.

Here is the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Float test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
        <div class="left-container">
            <div class="left-container-heading">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Float left doesn't work anymore since it is more than one line and I would like to know why and how to fix this.
            </p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css :

```
body {
    padding-top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

p, h, div {
    font-family: 'Corbel';
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

.left-container {
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 446px;
    height: 100%;
}

.left-container p {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.left-container-heading {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when your content is 1 line, your p element will only take very small space, it is aligned center just you don't realize it, try it **add width 100% to p element** to see if it is changed.

When your content is 2 lines, the width of the p element will take the longest line's width, and the content is still centered, and you found it is aligned center.

Answer (score 1):

It is coming like that because of the center alignment on the body. Once removed, it floats left

```css
body {
    padding-top: 2em;
   
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

p, h, div {
    font-family: 'Corbel';
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    float:left;
}

.left-container {
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 446px;
    height: 100%;
}

.left-container p {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.left-container-heading {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Float test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
        <div class="left-container">
            <div class="left-container-heading">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Float left doesn't work anymore since it is more than one line and I would like to know why and how to fix this.
            </p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha, too simple. Nice catch

Comment: @ellipsis Thanks. Why is it left-aligned when text is shorter than one line though ?